# how do I call a function with multiple values in javascript? phaser3

Tags: javascript, function, return, call

I'm a javascript beginner and I know I should read the tutorials and all.
However the tutorials only mention how to return a value within a function and I want to return multiple values. 
I'm using phaser 3 and I want to call a function that will give a coin physics.
here's the code

```js
function coins(coin) {
  coin.setBounce(1);
  coin.body.setGravityY(300);
  this.physics.add.collider(coin, platforms);
  this.physics.add.collider(player, coin, collectCoin, null, this);
  coin.setVelocityX(60);
  coin.setVelocityY(-300);
  coin.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
}
```

Please help me out, I've asked a couple of other places and have received no answers.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what exactly do you want to return?

Comment: you can return only one value in function. If you want to return multiple values combine them into one object  or one array and then return.

Comment: also, your title and question are asking two different things. Your title is asking how do you _call_ a function with multiple values (implying you want to pass multiple arguments to the function?), whereas your question is asking how you _return_ multiple values from function (implying you want to function to give back/return multiple values). It's unclear what exactly you're after here

Answer (score 2):

You can not return multiple values in js, but you can return an array or object with all values you need. Like:

```
return [val1, val2]   or   return {val1, val2}
```

And then access them:

```
answer[0]   or   answer.val1   or   answer["val1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple snippet here for you to a) show how to call a function with multiple arguments; and b) how return multiple values from a functino:

```js
class Coin {
  setBounce(value) {}
  setVelocityX(value) {}
  setVelocityY(value) {}
  setCollideWorldBounds(value) {}
  body = {
    setGravityY(value) {},
  };
}

var physics = {
  add: {
    collider(...args) {},
  },
};

function coins(coin, platforms, player, collectCoin) {
  coin.setBounce(1);
  coin.body.setGravityY(300);
  this.physics.add.collider(coin, platforms);
  this.physics.add.collider(player, coin, collectCoin, null, this);
  coin.setVelocityX(60);
  coin.setVelocityY(-300);
  coin.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

  /* 
    Below is how you return multiple values from a function
    in this case it's an array of values, but it could be an object too.
  */
  return ["Hello", "World"]; // <- this
}

let coin = new Coin();

// Below is how you call the function coins with multiple arguments
let result = coins(coin, "platforms", "player", "collectCoin");

console.log(result);
```

Let me know if you have any questions regarding the snippet above.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by return ["Hello", "World"];?

Comment: Just an example of a return with multiple values, what would you like to return from that function?

Comment: I would like to return everything

Comment: What do you mean everything?